# Vim motion commands in the Vim command-line

Tags: vim

Sometimes in Vim, I'm typing a command and realise that I could really use Vim's motion commands for navigating the command-line:

- `:s/somthing/else/`
- realise that I misspelled something.
- `Fmae` and be done with it.

Of course, trying this would just put `Fmae` at the end of the command. Is there any way to get (a subset of) the vim commands into the vim command-line? After all, that's what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When i need to edit a long command in command line, i use 
<kbd>q</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>

then i see a list of my last commands and i can move with regular vim motions and it's easy to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on the command line.

It will bring you to the same pop-up window as `q:` would bring you in normal mode. You can edit any command there. To execute press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As a bonus use the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in search mode as well
or use `q\` in normal mode

The Mnemonic for <kbd>F</kbd> in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> might be **Full history**, Find in history